# save list of dictionaries to database using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a list of dictionaries with three keys in each dictionary (title, url, score).

I would like to save each dictionary as a separate instance of a db model using sqlalchemy (i'm using sqlite3).

My list of dictionaries is saved into a variable called 'final'

Here is my db.Model:

```
class Favorite(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tile = db.Column(db.String(100))
    url = db.Column(db.String(150))
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __init__(self, title, url, score):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.score = score
```

As for my logic, this is what I have tried so far:

```
for post in final:
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
```

I've been getting the following error when running the program with this code:

```
UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__builtin__.dict' is not mapped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct instances of `Favorite` from each dict in the final list and then add it to session and commit.

```
for post in final:
  fav=Favorite(title=post.get('title'),url=post.get('url'),score=post.get('score'))
  db.session.add(fav)
  db.session.commit()
```

Comment: thank you, I knew I could commit each dictionary but for some reason couldn't think of the title=post.get('') logic that you provided. thank you again